# Referencing button in kivy

Tags: python, reference, widget, kivy

I was wondering is there anyway to reference a button in a .kv file in a python function without having to pass the button as a parameter to said function.  Sorry if this is a stupid question just started using this framework for Gesture Based UI.

Comment: Using `id`s are the way to go. I've got a video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEpHeuH7wNw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `id`s for this, example here:

```
Button:
    id: mybtn
    text: "Click"
```

Then, in python

```
self.ids.mybtn
```

SideNote: where you use `self.ids.mybtn` should be inside the class that contains this button

Comment: Thanks I actually found the answer on the docs page just as I asked this question.

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to edit the property of the button? I have a widget called GameMenu and a button called red in it and I'm trying to edit the text like this "            widget.ids["red"].text = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"" but it's not working

Comment: what is `widget`? and you should do: `self.ids.red.text = 'wateva'`

Comment: Sorry I was insanely tired writing that, I have the code `widget = GameMenu()`  and I'm trying to access the child red in GameMenu and change it's color